# Are instance and object different?

Tags: java, oop

Which of the following is(are) true?

1. b is not an instance of A
2. b is not an instance of C

```java
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}

B b=new B();
```

Comment: It's easy to check: `System.out.println(b instanceof A)` etc.

Comment: It's useful to think of a class as a template/blueprint, and an object an instance of that class.

Comment: thanx, i was confused between object and  its instance.

Comment: “instance” = “object”. “instance of T” = “object of type T”.

Answer (score 1):

To help you understand this concept you might replace abstract name `A, B, C` with common example such as `Animal, Feline, Cat`

Like

```java
class Animal {}
class Feline extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Feline {}
```

And your question becomes :

```
 1. One feline might not be an Animal
 2. One feline might not be a Cat
```

1. False every Feline instance is an Animal. Feline extends Animal
2. True not every feline are Cat. Feline does not extend Cat

As mentionned by @AndyTurner you might use `instanceOf` to check it out

Comment: This may be semantics, but technically, the statements in the assignment don't say "might" - this subtly alters the meaning. Otherwise, excellent example, 1+ from me.

Comment: we all agree that it's only a tip to get more familiar with the concept :D

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica this example is given in Oracle OCA Java SE 8 Programmer book ;)

Answer (score 0):

Search for the Liskov substitution principle on Google. It states that:

> In a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S - Wikipedia

> "b is not an instance of A" is false.

The local variable "b" is an instance of class "B". Class "B" is an instance of class "A" because it extends "A" and therefore everything that class "B" is, "A" is too.

> "b is not an instance of C" is true.

The local variable "b" is an instance of class "B". Class "B" is not an instance of C" because class "B" is everything that class "B" is and class "A", it knows nothing about class "C"